# add vertical scrollbar if page reaches certain height

Tags: html, css

I have searched on google for the answer but haven't found anything.  I have an absolute content position and I want to add a scrollbar o the web browser but only if it reaches a certain size.  This is a fullscreen website so I don't want a scrollbar at all times.  If I haven't made myself clear feel free to reply and I will get back to you asap.  Thank you.

Comment: [`overflow: auto`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)?

Comment: This happens automatically in browsers. So i'm not clear as to what is required

Comment: It is not working with overflow auto and it is not happening automatically.  Is there a reason why it wouldn't be registering?  I have this coding for my fullscreen bg html { background: url(images/wallbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }

Comment: Inspect the styles for your main containers, starting with `html`, then `body`, then your custom containers. Something important probably has `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Thank you bfavaretto.  overflow: hidden was being used on my footer.  I will find a work around.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.absPosDiv{
  max-height:700px; /* however tall you want before scrolls*/

  overflow:auto;

  /* if specifying x & y is important, use this instead of `overflow`*/
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I want to add the scrollbar to the browser not the absolute position part.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. Looks like you have it solved above anyways, so hopefully no harm done.